# Minus Operation Between CLOB column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper, clob

```
Create Table t1 (
table_id   number,
dose_detail clob,
CONSTRAINT t1_pk PRIMARY KEY (table_id)
);

Create Table t2 (
table_id   number,
dose_detail clob,
CONSTRAINT t2_pk PRIMARY KEY (table_id)
);
```

this clob column contains 14 million data and I need to perform MINUS operation between these two tables.

This method I used for minus operation :

```
SELECT table_id,
  DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input=> UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(dose_detail)) 
FROM t1
MINUS
SELECT table_id,
  DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input =>UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(dose_detail))
FROM t2;
```

This method taking longer time in execution like 1hr but I want to reduce execution time like 5-10 mins.

`DBMS_LOB.compare` is not suitable for my scenarios.

Others options please if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following statement:

```
SELECT table_id, DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input=> UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(dose_detail)) FROM t1 WHERE table_id IN (
SELECT table_id FROM (
SELECT table_id, DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(dose_detail,2)  
FROM t1
MINUS
SELECT table_id, DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(dose_detail,2) 
FROM t2));
```

as DBMS_CRYPTO supports CLOBS, whereas DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT does not, but the improvement depends on the amount of data returned by the inner MINUS statement and other factors. If you create a materialized view, the following statement is better:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_t
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST
ON COMMIT
AS
    SELECT table_id FROM (
    SELECT table_id, DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(dose_detail,2)  
    FROM t1
    MINUS
    SELECT table_id, DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(dose_detail,2) 
    FROM t2);
```

this way you can access your data using the statement:

```
SELECT table_id,
  DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input=> UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(dose_detail)) 
FROM t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could materialize CLOB hash using materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON t1;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_t1
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST
ON COMMIT
AS
SELECT  table_id,
 DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input=> UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(dose_detail)) AS dd_hash
FROM t1;
```

Same for second table and final query:

```
SELECT table_id, dd_hash FROM mv_t1
MINUS
SELECT table_id, dd_hash FROM mv_t2;
```

---

Second approach is handling CLOB hash by using INSERT/UPDATE trigger.

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD dd_hash VARCHAR2(100);

create trigger t1_trg
  before update or insert on t1
  for each row
begin
  :new.dd_hash := DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input=> 
                                          UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(:new.dose_detail));
end t1_trg;
```